# Code blocks are not supported in this context

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm trying to display a picture in my ASP Gridview, but the picture doesn't come from the database like the rest of the data does. It is generated based upon fields in the database. When I try to run a function within a gridview column, it gives me the error that code blocks are not supported in this context so I'm trying to find out what is the best way to accomplish this?

```
                <asp:GridView ID="g1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" PageSize="25" 
                        Width="100%" Font-Size="Medium" DataKeyNames="InternalReference">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="<% GetPicture1(Session("DealerID"), Eval("Uid")) %>"></asp:ImageField>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" HeaderText="View" SelectText="View" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="InternalReference" HeaderText="InternalReference" 
                            SortExpression="InternalReference" Visible="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="VehicleYear" HeaderText="Year" 
                            SortExpression="VehicleYear" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="VehicleMake" HeaderText="Make" 
                            SortExpression="VehicleMake" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="VehicleModel" HeaderText="Model" 
                            SortExpression="VehicleModel" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Mileage" HeaderText="Mileage" 
                            SortExpression="Mileage" ReadOnly="True" 
                            NullDisplayText="Call For Details" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,##0}" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" 
                            DataFormatString="{0:c}" ReadOnly="True" NullDisplayText="Call For Price" >
                        </asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1F1F1F" ForeColor="White" />
                    <RowStyle Height="30px" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

The first column is where I'm trying to insert the picture.

```
 <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="<% GetPicture(Session("DealerID"), Eval("Uid")) %>"></asp:ImageField>
```

Inside of the GetPicture() function, it takes in a dealer id, and a vehicle id then generates a URL for the image.

```
Public Function GetPicture(ByVal sDealerReference As String, ByVal sReference As String) As String
    If IO.File.Exists("Z:\FTP Customers\CarPhotos\" & Session("DealerID") & "\" & Trim(sReference) & ".0.jpg") Then
        Return "http://www.acarforless.com/carimages/" & Session("DealerID") & "/" & Trim(sReference) & ".0.jpg"
    Else
        Return "http://www.acarforless.com/carimages/nopicture.jpg"
    End If
End Function
```

What's the best way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the ImageField you could use a TemplateField with an Image control, since the Image control would allow you to specify a data binding expression for the ImageUrl, e.g.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# GetPicture(Session("DealerID"), Eval("Uid")) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: That was pretty straightforward. Thanks!